# On the intersection of two Orlicz spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory, banach-spaces, orlicz-spaces

It is well-known that if $1\leq p\leq q\leq \infty $ then

$$ L^p(X)\cap L^q(X)\subset L^r(X)\quad\quad  \text{whenever $r\in [p,q]$}\tag{I}\label{Eq}.$$

Indeed let $u\in L^p(X)\cap L^q(X)$. For some $0\leq \theta\leq 1$ we can write $$\frac{1}{r}=\frac{1-\theta}{p}+\frac{\theta}{q} $$

so that, $|u|^{1-\theta}\in L^{p/1-\theta}$ and $|u|^{\theta}\in L^{q/\theta}$ and the Hölder's inequality implies,

$$\|u\|_{L^r(X)}\leq  \|u^{1-\theta}\|_{L^{p/1-\theta}(X)}\|u^{\theta}\|_{L^{q/\theta}(X)}= \|u\|_{L^{p}(X)}^{1-\theta}\|u\|_{L^{q}(X)}^{\theta}.$$

Replacing $\theta=\frac{\frac{1}{r}- \frac{1}{p}}{\frac{1}{q}- \frac{1}{p}}$ by its value gives

$$\|u\|_{L^r(X)}\leq \|u\|_{L^{p}(X)}^{\frac{\frac{1}{q}- \frac{1}{r}}{\frac{1}{q}- \frac{1}{p}}}\|u\|_{L^{q}(X)}^{\frac{\frac{1}{r}- \frac{1}{p}}{\frac{1}{q}- \frac{1}{p}}}$$

**Question:** What is the analogue of the property \eqref{Eq} for Orlicz spaces of type $L^\phi(\Bbb R^d)$?
Any hint or references is welcome...

Recall the Orlicz space $L^\phi(\Bbb R^d)$:
\begin{align*}
 L^\phi(\Bbb R^d)&= \Big\{u: \Bbb R^d\to \Bbb R\text{ meas.}:~ \int_{\Bbb R^d}  \phi\Big(\frac{|u(x)|}{\lambda}\Big)d x<\infty ~~\text{for some $\lambda>0$}\Big\}.
 \end{align*}
The space $L^\phi(\Bbb R^d)$ is equipped with the Luxemburg norm $\|\cdot\|_{L^\phi(\Bbb R^d)}$ by
\begin{align}
 \|u\|_{L^\phi(\Bbb R^d)}=\inf \Big\{ \lambda>0~: \int_{\Bbb R^d} \phi\Big(\frac{|u(x)|}{\lambda}\Big)d x\leq 1\Big\}.
 \end{align}

Where $\phi$ is  a sufficiently nice Young function, e.g., $\phi$ is continuous, increasing, convex and in addition, the mapping $x\mapsto \frac{\phi(x)}{x}$, $x>0$ is increasing and satisfies
\begin{align*}
&\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\phi(x)}{x}= \lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{x}{\phi(x)}= 0.
\end{align*}

Comment: Well, $u^r \leq \max( u^p, u^q)$ for every $u\in [0,\infty)$, and this gives another proof that $L^p\cap L^q \subset L^r$. So the obvious modification using Young's functions should still work.

Comment: By the way, I think you should be asking about interpolation spaces and not just the intersection space. There are a lot of spaces that contain $L^\phi \cap L^\psi$. The interpolation spaces have the property that the norm can be bounded by something like $\|u\|_{L^\phi}^\theta \|u\|_{L^\psi}^{1-\theta}$. In that vein, Googling finds me https://eudml.org/doc/218150

Answer (score 3):

It's many years ago that I read it, but I think that some of the most general interpolation type results for Orlicz spaces were contained in [O’Neil, Richard, Integral transforms and tensor products on Orlicz spaces and $L(p,q)$ spaces, *J. Anal. Math.* **21**, 4–276 (1968)](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02787670) which is practically a monograph. Some other interpolation results are in the monograph [Rao, M. M. and Ren, Z. D., Theory of Orlicz spaces, Marcel Dekker, New York, 1991](https://catalog.princeton.edu/catalog/641203).